# Pikuach nefesh and matzoh shopping

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, matzah

Apropos of this viral post: https://twitter.com/Dr_Ophelian/status/1247386646317633536.

[image: chometz sophistry]

My understanding is that the principle of pikuach nefesh is not applied like this, but I am not certain why. Could someone explain it to me?

Additionally, what *should* one do if one only has access to chometz during Pesach (and one is in good health)? Am I right to assume that one should simply starve so long as one is in no real danger of injuring oneself by doing so?

Comment: It is not a matter of pikuach nefesh because one can get non chametz food. A person would have gotten kosher for pesach food over the last two weeks. Even fruit is kosher for pesach. Besides, it is more dangerous getting chametz food. I should add that it is possible to get food from the grocery store and it is **not** so dangerous to arrange for food from the grocery store without putting oneself into immediate deadly danger. For example, the community of Kiryat Yearim shows how it has been done. One should not become so panicked as to put oneself into pikuach nefesh by huddling in fear.

Comment: Cute, but also wildly false, full of inaccuracies and false equivalencies, and borderline dangerous, like many 'viral posts'. Just off the top: there are two issues being conflated here. There is a positive commandment to eat matzah, and a negative commandment to avoid eating chametz. Even working in the premise that one can't fulfill the first obligation (which is also dubious), that doesn't automatically allow one to transgress the second prohibition. That's like saying 'Shaking a Lulav is Pikuach Nefesh, so I'm going to eat a ham sandwich'. Can't eat matzah? Ok, but don't eat Chametz.